# Inconsistent behaviour in script and tag based approach in CF

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I wrote the below code block with cfset,

```
<cfset variables.test = 3>
<cfset variables.check = variables.test == 5>

<cfdump var="#variables#">
```

but this code block generated the error, "ColdFusion was looking at the following text: = "

While I wrote the above block within cfscript it provide me the correct reasult. Here is the cfscript code block.

```
<cfscript>
  variables.test = 3;
  variables.check = variables.test == 5;

  writeDump(variables);
</cfscript>
```

Here is the output of the cfscript code block.

[image]

I am not sure why script and tag based approach is behaving differently in this case.
Please suggest, why the tag based approach is generating an error.

Note: I have tested this in CF9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use "==" as a decision operator with tags. Use "EQ".

Try...

```html
<cfset variables.test = 3>
<cfset variables.check = variables.test EQ 5>

<cfdump var="#variables#">
```

Doc reference: "[The CFScript language: Expressions and operators](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7ffa.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7ff7)"